# In CSS, is [class][class] faster than [element][class]?

Tags: css, performance, browser, css-selectors

I know this is being picky but I'm working with an editor, which lints CSS and constantly complains

```
don't use adjoining classes > e.g.  .foo.bar
```

I'm ignoring the warnings, but it made me curious and can't find anything on it. Say I have:

```
  <ul class="foo bar"></ul>
```

which CSS selector is faster:

```
  ul.foo
  .bar.foo
```

I know selectors work right to left, so in both cases `foo` will be selected first, after which the browser has to find to find all `ul` in the selection(?) or all `.bar` elements(?).

**Question**:
In CSS, is `[class][class]` faster than `[element][class]`?

Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't tell which is faster, some profiling in webdevloper tools could help to tell it, but these are 2 very different selectors selecting 2 different sets of elements. They both work the same with your example but certainly not on a larger scope. P.S : I don't find it "picky", I would call it "attention to detail". On a page with a lot of elements to be parsed/selected, such optimizations could indeed make a difference. On "normal" pages, you wouldn't see anything for sure...

Comment: good point. Still curious.

Comment: Some good css rules: https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/css-web-performance-optimizations

Comment: I think it depend the browsers. Each browser declare codes by them self

Comment: try it yourself here: http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/csscreate.php and btw: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Comment: Worry about performance when you need to.

Comment: @Adam: I always worry about performance. In this case, I'm just curious...

Comment: Right-to-left selector matching does not work inside compound selectors, so there is no RTL evaluation on `ul.foo` or `.bar.foo`. There really is no reason to do so, especially considering that you cannot reorder a type selector (and a type selector is usually faster than a class selector). In RTL evaluation each element is tested against the key selector, and the key selector is the entire simple selector sequence. As to how or in what order each simple selector is evaluated, I'm pretty sure that's when implementations start to diverge.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a combined element and class selector. It's not performant. Just use the class. You're adding more specificity than necessary. If your ul needs to be more specific add another class that is only used by your ul's.  Take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Comment: I'm using these selectors solely for specificity = overwriting selectors from another framework I'm required to use and can't edit.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the sake of completeness: *why does css lint complain?*
Answer: Adjoining classes won't work for some very old browsers.

Quote from http://csslint.net/about.html:

> **Don't use adjoining classes**
>
> Adjoining classes look like .foo.bar. While technically allowed in CSS, *these aren't handled properly by **Internet Explorer 6** and earlier.*

Answer (score 2):

I think the general rule, and one that I've noticed myself is that it would be slightly quicker to use .class .class, although it would depend on the page itself (and I suppose what styles are being applied to an extent).

The speed of different selectors are generally agreed to be (from quickest to slowest);

ID -> Class -> Type -> Adjacent -> Child -> Descendant -> Universal -> Attribute -> Pseudo

Personally, and I suppose from a markup point of view too, I would also find it more advantageous to to use a class to select the first element. It avoids the possibility that an element of the same type could be affected by your CSS if one was to be added in the future.

This also then complies with a lot of the CSS writing guides which say that it makes more sense to use classes for styling purposes.

I've also remembered a [good article](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) which covers CSS efficiency. I'm hoping that article agrees with me now as I haven't read it for a while. Somewhere on the site they also look at the Block Element Modifier technique of writing CSS too, which is an interesting read and a nice starting place if you want to structure your CSS more efficiently (although it takes a bit of getting your head around the first time).